# Is possible to stop process while alert dialog finish its work?

Tags: java, android, database, while-loop, android-alertdialog

This is my method

```
public void getValues() {
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
            alertDialog.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null));

            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    field1 = (EditText)((Dialog) dialog).findViewById(R.id.field1);
                    field2 = (EditText)((Dialog) dialog).findViewById(R.id.field2);
                    errorMsg = (TextView)((Dialog) dialog).findViewById(R.id.login_error);
                    insert();
                }
            });

            /* When negative (No/cancel) button is clicked*/
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel(); // Your custom code
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
}
```

I need this method to create an input dialog that get the values that I need to check in my database.

These method work with this code

```
MyClass object = createObject();
while(!checkDB(object))
        {
            //Alert Dialog
            getValues();
        }
```

Well, `createObject()` get some information in another part of code and create an object from class `MyClass`.
checkDB search the object in my database;

My logic is: if the object that I search don't exists I will create it with the AlertDialog (method `getValues()` that with method `insert()` insert the new object in DB).

The problem is that if I use a while procedure, my AlertDialog won't create and so `!checkDB(object)` is always `false`!

How can I use this alertDialog in the while?

Thanks for answer

Edit:

I could use other 2 options:

```
MyClass object = createObject()
if(checkDB(object)
{
     continueOtherMethods();
}
else
{
     getValues();
}
```

or

```
MyClass object = createObject()
    if(!checkDB(object)
    {
         getValues();
    }
    continueOtherMethods();
```

The second choose is my original chose. The problem is that continueOtherMethods() work before that I get the data from AlertDialog.

With the first choose the problem is that when the application made correctely getValues(), don't made continueOtherMethods().

Comment: why not use an if instead of a while?

Comment: because when I use an if, the program go forward before than I finished to insert values in AlertBox

Comment: you must not stall the main thread using a while loop. if you want to wait with the rest of your code execution until dialog finishes, in the dialog,positive or negative onClick, call to a function that will continue with the rest of your code.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the main program is the program with while... The alert dialog have to show only in the first access to my application... Then checkDB is always true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your while loop is actually an endless loop on the main thread. that is why the alert dialog is never shown.

> How can I use this alertDialog in the while?

you shouldn't stall the main thread. replace the while statement to an if statement and continue your code execution after dialog finishes its work:

```
public void getValues() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        alertDialog.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null));

        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                field1 = (EditText)((Dialog) dialog).findViewById(R.id.field1);
                field2 = (EditText)((Dialog) dialog).findViewById(R.id.field2);
                errorMsg = (TextView)((Dialog) dialog).findViewById(R.id.login_error);
                insert();
                continueWhereLeftOff();
            }
        });

        /* When negative (No/cancel) button is clicked*/
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel(); // Your custom code
                continueWhereLeftOff();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
}


MyClass object = createObject();
if(!checkDB(object)){
    getValues();//Alert Dialog
}
else{
    continueWhereLeftOff();
}
//remove all code below this line to the continueWhereLeftOff()
```

Comment: The problem is that when I use getValues() I immediately use continueWhereLeftOff() with the data getting by getValues(). But if I do getValues(); continueWhereLeftOff(); the second method is used before than getValues() finished.

Comment: im not sure that i understood, could you please show a code snippet of the problem?

Comment: The correct sequence is this: 1) if checkDB(object) is true means that there is just the object in DB. So the program follow the correct methods (for example your continueWhereLeftOff(); 2) if checkDB(object) is not true means that I have to insert it in db. So I call the alert dialog (method getValues()) and I insert the values in DB. After this I have to do continueWhereLeftOff(). 3) If I delete while loop or if/else and I put getValues(); continueWhereLeftOff() immediately, appened that the second method don't wait that first method ended